# Moment JS week numbers in a year

Tags: mongodb, date, momentjs

I am trying to separate MongoDB records into date ranges in MomentJS.

In Mongo, each record has the `IsoDate` format of:

```
"date": {
    "$date": "2015-06-26T13:02:12.121Z"
},
```

My query returns the week and year:

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $project:
                {
                    week:
                    {
                        $week: '$date'
                    },
                    year:
                    {
                        $year: '$date'
                    },
                    dayOfWeek: {
                        $dayOfWeek:
                            [
                                '$date'
                            ]

                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group:
                {
                    _id: null,
                    distinctDate:
                    {
                        $addToSet:
                        {
                            year: '$year',
                            week: '$week'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    );
```

Which gives an output of weeks and the year:

```
week: 50
year: 2015
```

On the front end, I start my week on Monday and end on Sunday:

```
var monday = moment().day("Monday").isoWeek(weekNum).year(year).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
var sunday = moment().day("Sunday").isoWeek(weekNum).year(year).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

The output is:

```
12-26-2015 to 01-01-2015
12-19-2015 to 12-25-2015
12-12-2015 to 12-18-2015
```

The issue comes in when dealing with a new year in Moment:

**console.log('WeekNum', weekNum, monday, sunday, year):**

```
 WeekNum 0 12-28-2016 01-03-2016
```

If starting my week on Monday, `week num 0` for 2016 should start on January 4th, 2016, right? So week number `52` for 2015 will contain records from December 2015 and January 2016.

I can't figure out how to keep the week numbers consistent across the year.

The output should be:

```
12-26-2015 to 01-01-2016
12-19-2015 to 12-25-2015
12-12-2015 to 12-18-2015
```

I am thinking it might be better to capture this by getting the `ISOdate` for each record, then simply adding `7` days to it? And that's the week range?

```
var start_of_week = moment().dayOfYear(dayOfYear).year(year).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
var end_of_week = moment().dayOfYear(dayOfYear).year(year).add('days', 7).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

But this sometimes gives unexpected results. I'm getting overlapping week ranges:

```
01-01-2016 to 01-08-2016
12-29-2015 to 01-05-2016
12-27-2015 to 01-03-2016
12-26-2015 to 01-02-2016
```

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB notion of `$week` does match the notion of "ISO week" that are using in Moment.js. If you can, upgrade to at least version MongoDB 3.4 and start using `$isoWeek`, which will use the standard notion of an ISO week.

Otherwise, you'd have to make the Moment.js concept of "week" match Mongo by defining a custom locale for Moment.js in which "weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year."